# How to decode accented characters in a string that went through the $sanitize-method from angular

Tags: angularjs

Using the [$sanitize method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize) from ngSanitize, characters like ä, ö, ü, " get changed, for example:

```
haystack = "ö ä ü è é à"
console.log(haystack); // returns: ö ä ü è é à
haystack = $sanitize(haystack);
console.log(haystack); // returns: &#246; &#228; &#252; &#232; &#233; &#224;
```

I need to decode these accented characters.

Is there a concise way to decode accented characters after a $sanitize?

EDIT:

Why do I need to do this?

When the user enters a specific expression, the expression turns into a button. This happens via $sce.trustAsHtml().

If I don't sanitize the user input, then the user could write things like this:  alert("malicious javascript")  and then, the alert gets called. After the sanitize, my code comes, that replaces the specific expressions with a button.

EDIT 2:

I made a Plunker: http://jsfiddle.net/wop7zodd/28/

How would I use innerHtml, in my case, to fetch the data of the sanitized html?

Comment: Could you elaborate what your use case is? Why not just do `sanitized = $sanitize(haystack);` then you'll still have a reference to the original `haystack` before sanitizing..

Comment: @Ankh I updated my question. Do you need further inforamtions?

Comment: Either you are evaluating the input as HTML or you aren't. Do you really need `<` replaced by `&gt;` (for instance), but no other characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are actually inserting this value into the DOM to be evaluated, then you can fetch the plain text value.

```
> b = document.createElement('button')
<button>​</button>​
> b.innerHTML = '&#246; &#228; &#252; &#232; &#233; &#224;'
"&#246; &#228; &#252; &#232; &#233; &#224;"
> b.textContent
"ö ä ü è é à"
```

But you should reconsider what you're doing with this value and why you threw away the original input. Round-tripping an untrusted value through a sanitizer, evaluating as HTML, and getting the rendered output will be confusing to the next person who maintains this.

Comment: I added a Plunker and updated the question. Could you assist me in using the innerHtml? Thank you very much